# Unable to install swirl in R with the new update. Version 3.6.2

Tags: r, statistics, swirl

**When I type**

`install.packages("swirl")`

`library(swirl)`

**I get:**

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
mime    0.7    0.8              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) library("swirl")
Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “library("swirl")”
```

**How do I instal swirl in R with this?**

Comment: Wait a few days until the package is compiled, then try again

Comment: You are installing `swirl` package but you are getting message regarding `mime` package. That's strange. I have installed `swirl` in Windows 10 operating system R version 3.6.1 with absolutely no problem. You please run the `install.packages("swirl")` first, then call `library(swirl)`.

Comment: Now it givesme this: Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) install.packages("swirl")
Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “install.packages("swirl")”

Comment: You select Yes. Use `install.packages("swirl")` without " ".

Comment: How do I select Yes? it's not clickable, is it something I type in?

Comment: @olosi6 Can you post the screenshot?